# multi user chat server using TCP in c. How to send data to multiple clients?

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

I want to create a multi-user chat server using TCP in C in which, when a client sends a message to the server. it will be send to all other clients.

I cannot find any method to send data to multiple clients, is there some method to iterate over all the clients which are connected to the socket or some method to broadcast a message to all clients.

Here is my code

**server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> //for sock()
#include <string.h>//for using memset
#include <arpa/inet.h>// for inet_addr()
#include <unistd.h>//for using write() function


int main(){


int sock=0, client_conn=0,counter=0,pid;
char data_send[1024],data_received[1024];
struct sockaddr_in ServerIp;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


 memset(&ServerIp,'0',sizeof(ServerIp) );
 ServerIp.sin_family = AF_INET;
 ServerIp.sin_port = htons(1234);
 ServerIp.sin_addr . s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


 if(   bind( sock,(struct sockaddr* )&ServerIp, sizeof(ServerIp)) == -1 )
    printf("\n Socket binding failed ");

if( listen(sock,20) == -1) 
    printf("Error\n");
else    
    printf("\n Server started\n");

for(;;){
    label:

    client_conn = accept( sock, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
    pid = fork();
    if( pid < 0 )
        printf("\n Process creation failed ");
    else if( pid > 0 ){
        counter++;
        ///close(client_conn); 
        goto label;
    }   
    else{
        counter++;
        if( recv(client_conn, data_received, 1024, 0 ) == -1 )
            printf(" Error !! cannot get response \n");

        printf(" data from client is %s\n",data_received);
        sprintf(data_send," Hi client %d !! from server ",counter);
        write( client_conn, data_send, sizeof(data_send) );

    }

}   


close( sock );

return 0;
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> //for sock()
#include <string.h>//for using memset
#include <arpa/inet.h>// for inet_addr()
#include <unistd.h>//for using write() function

int main(){
enter code here
    char data_received[1024],data_send[1024];
int sock=0;
struct sockaddr_in ServerIp;


if( (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM ,0 )) == -1 )
    printf(" socket creation failed ");


 ServerIp.sin_family = AF_INET;
 ServerIp.sin_port = htons(1234);
 ServerIp.sin_addr . s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");   


 if( (connect( sock, (struct sockaddr *)&ServerIp, sizeof(ServerIp) )) == -1 ){
    printf("\n connection to the socket failed ");
    exit(0);
}
 else
    printf("\n connected to socket \n");

strcpy(data_send,"hello server");
if( send(sock,data_send,sizeof(data_send),0) == -1 )
    printf("sending failed ");


while(1){
 printf("\n waiting for respose !! \n");    


 if( recv(sock, data_received, 1024, 0 ) == -1 )
    printf(" Error !! cannot get response |n");
 else
    printf("\n Response Received is : %s", data_received );
    }
```

}

any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a simple and easy way to do it using pthread. Here is the code

**server code**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int clients[20];
int n=0;

void sendtoall(char *msg,int curr){
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(clients[i] != curr) {
            if(send(clients[i],msg,strlen(msg),0) < 0) {
                printf("sending failure \n");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void *recvmg(void *client_sock){
    int sock = *((int *)client_sock);
    char msg[500];
    int len;
    while((len = recv(sock,msg,500,0)) > 0) {
        msg[len] = '\0';
        sendtoall(msg,sock);
    }

}

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in ServerIp;
    pthread_t recvt;
    int sock=0 , Client_sock=0;

    ServerIp.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerIp.sin_port = htons(1234);
    ServerIp.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sock = socket( AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    if( bind( sock, (struct sockaddr *)&ServerIp, sizeof(ServerIp)) == -1 )
        printf("cannot bind, error!! \n");
    else
        printf("Server Started\n");

    if( listen( sock ,20 ) == -1 )
        printf("listening failed \n");

    while(1){
        if( (Client_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)NULL,NULL)) < 0 )
            printf("accept failed  \n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        clients[n]= Client_sock;
        n++;
        // creating a thread for each client 
        pthread_create(&recvt,NULL,(void *)recvmg,&Client_sock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return 0; 

}
```

**client code**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char msg[500];

void *recvmg(void *my_sock)
{
    int sock = *((int *)my_sock);
    int len;
    // client thread always ready to receive message
    while((len = recv(sock,msg,500,0)) > 0) {
        msg[len] = '\0';
        fputs(msg,stdout);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    pthread_t recvt;
    int len;
    int sock;
    char send_msg[500];
    struct sockaddr_in ServerIp;
    char client_name[100];
    strcpy(client_name, argv[1]);
    sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    ServerIp.sin_port = htons(1234);
    ServerIp.sin_family= AF_INET;
    ServerIp.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if( (connect( sock ,(struct sockaddr *)&ServerIp,sizeof(ServerIp))) == -1 )
        printf("\n connection to socket failed \n");

    //creating a client thread which is always waiting for a message
    pthread_create(&recvt,NULL,(void *)recvmg,&sock);

    //ready to read a message from console
    while(fgets(msg,500,stdin) > 0) {
        strcpy(send_msg,client_name);
        strcat(send_msg,":");
        strcat(send_msg,msg);
        len = write(sock,send_msg,strlen(send_msg));
        if(len < 0) 
            printf("\n message not sent \n");
    }

    //thread is closed
    pthread_join(recvt,NULL);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

To see the output see https://codingile.wordpress.com/multiuser-chat-server-in-c/

Answer (score 4):

The broadcast is done by keeping a list of all the connected clients and their file descriptors updated, and by iterating through it to send each client the message (you can't do a broadcast in TCP as you would in UDP because TCP is a connected protocol while UDP isn't).

---

If it can be of any use, here is a repo with a multi-user TCP server I made in C for a school project: https://github.com/DatPenguin/TCPServer. It is not a chat, but the TCP part should be the same.

In the `client` folder is the code for the client side, while the server side is in the `server` folder.

Comment: is there any method other than using file descriptors. like some function to get the list of all connected clients

Comment: You already use file descriptors : `client_conn` is one. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

Comment: the program in the repo you provide is too complex to understand . is there any alternatives?

Comment: The algorithm is in `server/main.c`, in the `run()` function. It has comments and I have explained the basic answer for the broadcast earlier. Each function has an explicit name. What don't you understand?

Comment: I took the freedom to move the correct answer in your answer to the top of your answer.